# Why can i create local variables in a view builder in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I think I used to get error complaining about having a local variable in the view builder. I also looked up online and found this:
[Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789654/closure-containing-a-declaration-cannot-be-used-with-function-builder-viewbuild?rq=1)

However, today when I tried it out, I was able to create local variables in a view builder without any problem:

```
  @ViewBuilder
  private var foo: some View {
    let something = 3
    Text("foo")
    Text("bar")
  }
```

May I know why?

Comment: They just fixed function builder transform https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md#the-function-builder-transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SwiftUI was first released (in 2019), the Swift language didn't allow local declarations (like `let something = 3`) inside what were then called “function builders”. However, function builders evolved into what are now called “result builders” and do support local declarations as of Swift 5.4.

This behavior is documented in [SE-0289 Result Builders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#declaration-statements):

> ##### Declaration statements
>
> Local declarations are left alone by the transformation. This allows developers to factor out subexpressions freely to clarify their code, without affecting the result builder transformation.